# How can I prevent my HTTP Get request from being cached in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm having a weird bug that pop up out of no where. I'm almost done with my app and I'm testing it, and then I noticed the data isn't being updated. The database gets updated, and I can hit the url directly and see the data is being returned from the server correctly, but when I print the data in Swift, it doesn't change.

Once I rerun the app it will change (most of the time)

I'm using Alamofire, but I've also tried two other methods:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

and

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

All 3 print out the same data.

I'm guessing it's a caching problem in Swift, but I haven't set anything to tell Swift to cache the data, and it's been working fine for the last few weeks.

The only thing I've done today was make a Git repo for my project.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

---

***edit:**

Using Abhi Beckert's answer I tried this:

Conforming to the delegate NSURLConnectionDelegate

Adding:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willCacheResponse cachedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse) -> NSCachedURLResponse?
{
  return nil // never cache anything. ever.
}
```

and then to make the call:

```
let url:NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://coffee.datausadev.com/api/getCoffeeBrands")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

This method still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your controller object as the delegate for the `NSURLConnection`:

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
self.currentConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
```

This also requires making self conform to the data source:

```
class MyController: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
```

And disable caching with the relevant delegate method:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willCacheResponse cachedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse) -> NSCachedURLResponse?
{
  return nil // never cache anything. ever.
}
```

The `.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` option on the URL request will disable reading the cache, and the `willCacheResponse` delegate method disables writing to the cache. You need to use both of them.

Unfortunately this means you cannot use the `sendAsynchronousRequest` convenience method and block callback - instead you'll have to use the delegate methods in `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` to process the response. Basically you've got to create an `NSMutableData` object, and append to it as data comes in from the connection, until the connection tells you the request is finished or failed — then you can do something with the data.

As far as I know, it is impossible to fully disable caching while using `sendAsynchronousRequest`. You might want to create a wrapper class around `NSURLConnection` to make your code neater.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the above is doable when using NSUrlSession (introduced in iOS7) by using an ephemeral configuration and invalidating the session after finishing the download (which is going to clear the cache according to Apple docs)

Comment: I'm getting "class does not have a member named currentConnection" I edited my post to show what I tried. It still didn't work though.

Comment: @Kolby you need to have an instance variable on your class for currentConnection. Have a read of Apple's documentation on how to use NSURLConnection, they have all the code there - I only posted the parts relevant to caching.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Swift error.

Behind the scenes NSURLSession follows certain policies depending on the configuration object backing it.

The default configuration (the one you are using via the sharedSession singleton) uses the "currently set global NSURLCache, NSHTTPCookieStorage, and NSURLCredentialStorage objects and is based on the default configuration",  via [NSUrlSession Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession)

Your options:

1. Use the "ephemeral" configuration that pretty much caches nothing (think private browsing mode),
2. Setup a configuration yourself and set the caching and other policies to whatever suits your needs.

Don't forget to take into account the server's policies as well. Either consult the documentation or if there is not any, try to make the best decisions based on the http headers you get back as a response to your requests.

**Edit:** I only now noticed you originally used Alamofire. All it (and AF in Objective-c) does, is provide a convenient, higher level of doing the same thing you do with NSURLSession and NSURLConnection before iOS7. They both have to let you customize caching, go through their docs.

Comment: Ya I would really like to find a way to use Alamofire. I've gone through their docs a few time and the only thing it mentions about caching is: "Caching is handled on the system framework level by NSURLCache."

Comment: Are you sure they mention nothing about playing around with caches yourself? I know that AFNetworking, Alamofire's Objective-C cousin allows you to do it, and it's written by the same people. It's an open source project, you can always dig in and add it yourself :)

Comment: That's what I started to do on Friday before posting this. This is my first Swift app so I'm still learning things as I go. Do you mind providing code for the ephemeral configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I tired everything, was not helpfull . This solution Worked For me in (**Swift 3)**

I called **destroyCache()** function after every HttpResponse.

```
 public static func destroyCache() {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsUrl =  fileManager.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
        let documentsPath = documentsUrl.path
        let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! as String
        do {
            if let documentPath = documentsPath
            {
                let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(documentPath)/\(bundleIdentifier)")
                for fileName in fileNames {
                    let filePathName = "\(documentPath)/\(bundleIdentifier)/\(fileName)"
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePathName)
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print("Could not clear: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a consistent way to get the most recent file using the mecanism called `Cache Busting`. This is commonly used in web development.

Add a randomly generated query string to the url at each call of the request:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SomeGitUser/3d8fc828/raw?cachebust=\(UUID().uuidString)")
```

This will trick the network into thinking it is a brand new url and it will fetch its data directly from the server instead of looking into an existing cache.